# lua recursion vs python recursion

Tags: python, recursion, lua, stack, overflow

I wrote a simple program to learn the basics of lua but it created a stack overflow. Writing the exact same program in python though did the job perfectly. 
Lua code:

```
function tprint (tbl, indent)
  if not indent then indent = 0 end
  for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
    formatting = string.rep("  ", indent) .. k .. ": "
    if type(v) == "table" then
      print(formatting)
      tprint(v, indent+1)
    else
      print(formatting .. v)
    end
  end
end

function encryptNumber(num)
    return 3 * num + 2
end

function decryptNumber(num)
    return (num - 2) / 3
end

function encryptString(str)
    enstr = ""
    for i = 1,string.len(str) do
        enstr = enstr..string.char((string.byte(str,i) + 19) % 255)
    end
    return enstr
end

function decryptString(str)
    destr = ""
    for i = 1,string.len(str) do
        destr = destr..string.char((string.byte(str,i) - 19) % 255)
    end
    return destr
end

function encryptTable(t)
    newt = {}
    for i,j in pairs(t) do
        newi = encrypt(i)
        newj = encrypt(j)
        newt[newi] = newj
    end
    return newt
end

function decryptTable(t)
    newt = {}
    for i,j in pairs(t) do
        newi = decrypt(i)
        newj = decrypt(j)
        newt[newi] = newj
    end
    return newt
end

function encrypt(obj)
    if type(obj) == "number" then
        return encryptNumber(obj)
    end
    if type(obj) == "string" then
        return encryptString(obj)
    end
    if type(obj) == "table" then
        retval = encryptTable(obj)
        return retval
    end
end

function decrypt(obj)
    if type(obj) == "number" then
        return decryptNumber(obj)
    end
    if type(obj) == "string" then
        return decryptString(obj)
    end
    if type(obj) == "table" then
        retval = decryptTable(obj)
        return retval
    end
end

test = {1, {'a'}, '3'}
tprint(test)
tprint(encrypt(test))
tprint(decrypt(encrypt(test)))
```

The same exact code in python that works perfectly well:

```
def encryptNumber(num):
    return 3 * num + 2


def decryptNumber(num):
    return (num - 2) / 3


def encryptString(str):
    enstr = ""
    for i in range(len(str)): 
        enstr = enstr + chr((ord(str[i]) + 19) % 255)
    return enstr


def decryptString(str):
    destr = ""
    for i in range(len(str)): 
        destr = destr + chr((ord(str[i]) - 19) % 255)
    return destr


def encryptTable(t):
    newt = {}
    for i in t: 
        newi = encrypt(i)
        newj = encrypt(t[i])
        newt[newi] = newj
    return newt


def decryptTable(t):
    newt = {}
    for i in t: 
        newi = decrypt(i)
        newj = decrypt(t[i])
        newt[newi] = newj
    return newt


def encrypt(obj):
    if type(obj) == int:
        return encryptNumber(obj)

    if type(obj) == str:
        return encryptString(obj)

    if type(obj) == dict:
        return encryptTable(obj)



def decrypt(obj):
    if type(obj) == int:
        return decryptNumber(obj)

    if type(obj) == str:
        return decryptString(obj)

    if type(obj) == dict:
        return decryptTable(obj)

test = {2: {1:2}, 1: {'a': {'c':'d'}}}
print test
print encrypt(test)
print decrypt(encrypt(test))
```

is there a difference between recursion in lua vs recursion in python and the problem exists because of that? Or is the logic mistaken?

Comment: Use local variables.

Comment: if  you are reffering to retval = encrypt... thing it was originally:

Comment: return encrypt... with no use of variables at all

Comment: oh i understood, thanks a lot!

Comment: I see the recursion in LUA, but I don't see the recursion in the python code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Debug! Single step through the code, examine the execution path and variable values. Learning debugging is as important as learning programming. Dubug It, [Just Do It](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXsQAXx_ao0).